# How to add BatchNormalization loss to gradient calculation in tensorflow 2.0 using keras subclass API

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

Using the keras subclass API it is easy enough to add a a batch normalization layer however the layer.losses list always appears empty. What is the correct method of including in the train loss when doing `tape.gradient(loss, lossmodel.trainable_variables)` where lossmodel is some separate keras subclass model defining a more complicated loss function that must include the gradient losses?

For example, this is minimal model with ONLY the batch norm layer. It has no loss AFAIK

```
class M(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, axis):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=axis, scale=False, center=True, virtual_batch_size=1, input_shape=(6,))

    def call(self, x):
        out = self.layer(x)
        return out

m = M(1)
In [77]: m.layer.losses
Out[77]: []
```

Comment: Which loss do you expect the batch normalization layer should add?

Comment: huh? It should add the online mean and variance estimation loss. The batch part of batch normalization is kind of a stability hack. Just wanted the easy online shift and scale learner, i.e. a r.v. transformer that learns the distribution online. Seems like tensorflow_probability will be the way to do this properly in the future with actual bijective transformations. I still have not understood how anyone is training batch norm like this though. I suspect there is some flag I'm mising or some tf 2.0 interaction that is not working properly.

Comment: And to be more clean, from what I am reading the moving_mean etc should be the params being updated using the gradient of the loss.

Comment: *clear. typing more to allow comment.